# Difference between 2 different kinds of counting problems both of which can be solved by Product Rule

Tags: combinatorics

$1.$ A gymnastics team has $7$ members. The coach must assign one member to compete in each of the $4$ event finals (floor exercise, balance beam, vault, uneven parallel bars). How many different assignments are possible if members are allowed to compete in more than one event? How many if no member can compete in more than one event?

$2.$ Suppose you have $3$ pairs of pants, $5$ shirts and $2$ pairs of shoes. How many outfits do you have?

The second one is basically set up for Product Rule. We have $3$ sets with $3, 5, 2$ possibilities within each, respectively. By PR there are $30$ outfits.

How come we can't do something like that for the first problem? We have two sets with seven and four possibilities within each. But the answers are nowhere near $28$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

7 members, we need to pick someone to compete in each of the 4 events.  So, we have **4** sets with **7** possibilities within each.

For the first interpretation, we are allowed to have someone compete in multiple events.  Break it up as the following:  Step1(Pick who competes for floor exercise), Step2(Pick who competes for balance beam), Step3(Pick who competes for vault), Step4(Pick who competes for bars).  As we allow in the first interpretation people to compete multiple times, there are 7 choices at each step.  Hence, $7\cdot 7\cdot 7\cdot 7 = 7^4$.

If we disallow atheletes from competing in multiple events, each time you pick someone, they are removed from the available roster to pick from for the next event(s).  It is again broken into steps: Step1(Pick who competes for floor exercise), Step2(Pick who competes for balance beam), Step3(Pick who competes for vault), Step4(Pick who competes for bars).  In this case, there are 7 choices for step 1, and regardless who was chosen for step1 there will be 6 choices remaining for step 2, 5 remaining for step 3, and 4 remaining for step 4, for $840=7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4 = \frac{7!}{3!} = P(7,4) = ~_7P_4$ possibilities.

Comment: "7 members, we need to pick someone to compete in each of the 4 events. So, we have 4 sets with 7 possibilities within each."                                                            Basically this how I attack these problems: I extract the sets involved and multiply over their members taking into account repetition. The "set extraction" seems to be the hardest part. What are some cues I could look out for when solving permutation related problems?

Comment: @permutation In general, the multiplication principle states that if you can separate the overall process into steps and regardless which choice was made at each step the available *number* of choices remains the same at all subsequent steps(it is okay if the specific choices available change so long as the number of choices remains the same), then the overall number of ways to complete the total process is the product of the number of choices at each step.  As for how to find queues, figure out what questions need to be asked and with what possible answers to completely describe the scenario.

Comment: In this case, it was "who competed for floor exercises?" and "who competed for balance beams?" etc...  Similarly it could be "who came in first place?" "who came in second place?" etc... for questions about number of ways in which a race could finish, or "what number is used in the triple?" "what suits were used in the triple?" etc... when talking about how many different full house hands exist in poker. So long as the questions were picked in such a way that you count each situation exactly once or at least divide by symmetry (such as in combinations), multiplication principle is quite useful

Answer (score 0):

The product rule can be used in #1, in a sense.

In the first part of #1, each of the 4 events can have any of the 7 members.  So there are 7 candidates for the floor, 7 for the balance, etc.  You can think of four hats, each one having all 7 names in it.  How many ways can you draw 4 names?

In the second part, imagine assigning the team by going down the events.  How many ways can you fill the first event?  7.  Then there are only 6 left to fill out the next, then 5, etc...

Answer (score 0):

If a member can compete in more than one event, what we are counting is the number of functions from a set with 4 elements (the events) to a set with 7 elements  (the people). For each of the 4 events we may choose one out of 7 people, and there are 7 ways to do that. We do this 4 times, so the number of possibilities is 7 multiplied by itself 4 times, which is $7^4$. Although the product rule doesn't solve the entire problem, it can be used for part if it.

If each person can participate in at most one event, then we are choosing 4 people out of 7 where order matters. There are 7 ways to choose the first person, 6 for the second, 5 for the third, and 4 for the fourth. We multiply these (using the "product rule") to get the answer.

In summary, while the first problem required a bit more reasoning, in the end we ended up multiplying numbers of possibilities to get the answer.